# Hibernate and multiple DB connections

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

Having following architecture:

[image: Server architecture]

So every server (GS) can talk to each database server (DB, PostgreSQL). The servers (GS) are running Spring Boot with Hibernate.

As far as I know Hibernate does a lot of caching (I'm new working with Hibernate). What happens when request 1 comes in, got handled by gs1 and changes the data on db1. Request 2 comes in, gets handled by gd2 and worked on the data of db1 which got cached before so it will work with outdated data. How to handle that problem?

Comment: when you configure a session factory, it is for a given DB server. you want your application to connect to multiple DB servers. so you will need multiple session factories and way to inject those wherever required.

Comment: @Atul: I adjusted my question. Now it is more specific.

Comment: Does this help you? Google hibernate entity versioning, locking  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html